# Как импортировать библиотеки "по кругу"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

У меня есть файл **User.py** и он импортирует **Errors.py** и тот в свою очередь импортирует **User.py**

**User.py**

```py
from . import Errors

...

raise Errors.ArgumentError
```

**Errors.py**

```py
from . import User

...

user = User()
user.test() # raise Errors.ArgumentError
```

И мне нужен любой способ получить классы без "Кругового" импорта

Answer (score 0):

При импорте библиотеки происходит выполнение кода указанного модуля, соответственно, цикличный импорт работать не будет. Вам нужно перераспределить функционал этих модулей, так чтобы избавиться от цикличной зависимости.